# Parallel run of qiskit circuits

Tags: qiskit, simulation

I am trying to run simulation instances of a parametrized circuit in parallel but my algorithm is extremely slow. Excuse my ignorance, but I just want to be sure that the circuits are indeed running in parallel.

Here is my execution workflow:

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator',
                          max_parallel_threads=N_threads,
                          max_parallel_experiments=N_threads,
                          optimization_level=3,
                         precision="single")

parametrized_circuits = CreateCircuits()

transpiled = transpile(parametrized_circuits, backend=backend)

experiments = []
for i in range(N):
    experiments.append(transpiled[i].assign_parameters(a))

job = execute(experiments, backend=backend, optimization_level=0)
```

So, my first question

**1. Is the structure efficient? E.g. Are the circuits transpiled only once? Or does `execute` re-transpile them? (I have read this function is just a wrapper for `transpile` and `run`)**

When I run my experiments in a `12-core` node, most cores seem to be under-utilized (atmost 10%, some even lower), while the experiment taking ages to complete. I have also read this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23353/how-to-order-results-after-multi-circuit-qiskit-execute-parallel-run) regarding reordering. My results come out with the same order as if the circuits were simulated serially, which makes me even more suspicious.

**2. Are my circuits really running in parallel? Is there something I miss?**

Comment: On your first question: `transpiled = transpile(parametrized_circuits, backend=backend)` is unnecessary. `execute` will transpile on a bind circuited, which is much more efficient. The rumours are true, `execute` function is just a wrapper for `transpile` and `run`.

Comment: Also, `optimization_level` is not a backend option. You can checkout the backend options with `backend.options`

Comment: @luciano Then, should I transpile the parametrized circuits once and  then repeatedly assign and run or just assign and execute (auto-transpile) at every run?

Comment: if the transpilation process is not your bottleneck, then just execute.